# List of ad-hoc polymorphic functions with same return value type isn't passing type checking

Tags: haskell

I have a type with different fields  which looks something like this

```hs
data MyType = MyType
    { field1 :: String
    , field2 :: Bool
    , field3 :: Int }
    deriving Show
```

Also i have a function, which checks, if the field value isn't equal to some value that i don't need.

```hs
check :: Eq b => MyType -> (MyType -> b) -> b -> IO (Maybe ())
check base f fail_value = do
    case (f base) == fail_value of
        True -> do
           putStrLn "Bad Bad Bad"
           return Nothing
        _ -> return . Just $ ()
```

Now i want to create a list of results of applying `check` with different arguments.

```hs
let example = MyType [] False 0
let test = check example -- Here is the problem.
let tests = [ test field1 []
            , test field2 False
            , test field3 0 ]
```

The type of expressions is supposed to be same, ghci also confirming.

```hs
check example field1 []    :: IO (Maybe ())
check example field2 False :: IO (Maybe ())
check example field3 0     :: IO (Maybe ())
```

But the problem is, that there is the type checking error, despite the type of `tests` expression supposed to be `[IO (Maybe ())]`. Can you tell me please, why this doesn't work as i think is suppose to work? Thank you so much.

The error from ghci:

```
Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Bool’
      Expected type: MyType -> [Char]
        Actual type: MyType -> Bool
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. When loading a file with the above code in GHCi, it loads and reports the type of `tests` as `tests :: [IO (Maybe ())]`.

Comment: @MarkSeemann oh, excuse me. In fact i forgot the fact, that i declared local function like 
let check' = check example and then was using it in list expressions. Without this, it works fine. Does it has connection to the monomorphism restriction?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

*Short*: pragma NoMonomorphismRestriction helped.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
```

Instead of this.

```hs
let example = MyType [] False 0
let tests = [ check example field1 []
            , check example field2 False
            , check example field3 0 ]
```

In my actual code I was using something like this:

```hs
let example = MyType [] False 0
let test' = check example -- Here it is...
let tests = [ test' field1 []
            , test' field2 False
            , test' field3 0 ]
```

And was getting error in type check, with this test' function. Without it, it is actually working fine.

There is some non-intuitive thing in type inference.
https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction